# Concise way to compare multiple element values in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, comparison

Perhaps I missed something, but is there a better/more concise way of writing something like this:

```
var a=1,
    b=2,
    c=3;
if(a===1 && b===1 && c===1){ do something };
```

or

```
if(a===1 || b===1 || c===1){ do something };
```

I'm trying to keep the code small, so am not looking for iterating through arrays, etc like proposed in pages I've come across. I would think that there would be something (at least for the first example where they are all the same) that would look like

```
if(a=b=c===1){ do something? };
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. You have to check them individually. JavaScript just doesn't have an operator for what you're trying to do.

Your `if(a=b=c===1){ ...` (which I realize was just an example) would *set* `a` and `b` to be `true` (if `c===1`) or `false` (if it didn't) and then branch based only on `c===1`.

I mean, for that *specific* case, there are a couple of math approaches, but in the general case, no.

Comment: Although there are a lot of other excellent responses to this question, it seems that this one is the closest. @squint solution is nice and I may use that in something down the road though Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can take a functional approach, and create a simple comparison function generator:

```
function eq(val) {
    return function(x) {
        return x === val
    }
}
```

And then use `.every` for the `&&`:

```
if ([a,b,c].every(eq(1))) {
    // all were equal
}
```

Or use `.some` for the `||`:

```
if ([a,b,c].some(eq(1))) {
    // at least one was equal
}
```

---

You could also create a function that receives the result of a condition and a function to invoke when the condition was true:

```
function when(cond, fn) {
    if (cond)
        fn.call.apply(fn, [].slice.call(arguments, 2))
}
```

And encapsulate your `if` body into a function...

```
function doIt(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log("doing it!")
    console.log(this, arg1, arg2)
}
```

---

Then use it like this:

```
when([a,b,c].every(eq(1)), doIt, null, "foo", "bar")
```

The third argument to `when` sets the `this` value of the callback, and subsequent arguments are passed as arguments to the callback.

Comment: +1 I like the functional approach, if it's something that comes up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much you want to invest, that would be a possible solution:

```
var slice=Function.call.bind([].slice)

var checkCondition=function(condition){ 
    return function(){
        return slice(arguments).reduce(function(o,n){
            return o && o == condition(n);
        },true);
    }
}

greater5=checkCondition(function(x){ return x>5; });

console.log(greater5(4,7));
```

If you only have one or two times in your code where you have to check multiple variables it would be absolutely overkill. But if you have multiple places with varying arguments, it might help.

You could easily define new checks by definition of another function and add as many variables as you want.

Comment: Keep in mind that `.reduce()` doesn't short circuit the evaluation, so the result you'll get will be whether the result of the last condition check matches the result of the second to last. So `g5(4,4); // true`...`g5(4,4,4); // false`...and a continued alternation. You could add short-circuiting to the evaluation in the `.reduce()` return value to handle it. `return o && o == condition(n);`